# Logical condition not working

Tags: powershell

i need help with PowerShell

I need help with my script in logical comparison using a Csv: 
`SamAccountName`,`Othertelephone`,`employeeId`,`PreferredLanguage`
I have developed a script which update AD user details based on certain condition.

1. `EmployeeID` should be ABC and XYZ only, no other ID should be taken. and this field can be blank.
2. Sam Account cannot be blank
3. `Othertelephone` cannot be blank
4. `PreferredLanguage` should be EN|ES only.no other parameter should be taken and this field can be blank.

script will update user if above conditions are met.

I am stuck at point 1, it is not ignoring the blank field. if I leave it blank it executes the code block.

```
IF($_.employeeId -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ' or $_EmployeeId.trim() -eq "") 
{ write-output " Id is not proper" }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need an -OR and another condition test.  Just add another qualifier in your regex:

```
$_.EmployeeID -notmatch '^(ABC|XYZ|\s*)$'
```

That will test for whitespace or a null string, in addition to the ABC and XYZ values.

Edit: If the ABC and XYZ value tests need to be unbounded (they can appear anywhere in the attribute value), isolate the begin and end anchors to just the null/whitespace test:

```
 $_.EmployeeID -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ|^\s*$'
```

Comment: Depending on what the real values of `'ABC|XYZ'` not have boundaries could have unexpected results. This is the answer I was going to post

Comment: If ABC and XYZ need to be unbounded, the anchors can be isolated to just the null/whitespace test - e.g. $_.EmployeeID -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ|^\s*$'

Answer (score 0):

```
$_.employeeId -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ' or $_EmployeeId.trim() -eq ""
```

You need a `-` before `or` here and a `.` after `$_` in the second test.

```
$_.employeeId -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ' -or $_.EmployeeId.trim() -eq ""
```

However, this statement will still evaluate to `$true` if `EmployeeId` is empty because an empty ID also meets your first test's criteria - empty does not match `ABC` or `XYZ`

I think you really want this:

```
$_.employeeId -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ' -and $_.EmployeeId.trim() -ne ""
```

You might want to test for `$null` as well as the empty string there.

Comment: Actualy i missed "-or" and $_. sorry. however -and will check both condition to be true and will exute the code block. i allready tried with -and -or...but it gives same result...no improvement

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$_.employeeId -ne "ABC" -and $_.employeeId -ne "XYZ" -and $_.employeeId -ne ""
```

Comment: Hi, it is same as $_.employeeId -notmatch 'ABC|XYZ' -and $_.EmployeeId.trim() -ne "".............................there is no diffrence on both outcome ..only syntax is diffrent